# How to create thumbnails with ExactImage?

Tags: linux, command-line, thumbnails

I'm trying to create thumbnails using ExactImage command-line tools. I need the output images to be with equal dimensions like 100x100 or 200x200. Can somebody help with that?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer "convert" from ImageMagick package, but if you really wanna use exactimage, you have to use econvert command, but econvert don't works with pixel values, only scalable, any way, you can use that:

```
econvert -i image.jpg --thumbnail 0.50 -o thumb.jpg
```

**0.50 does mean 50%, or try "convert":**

```
convert -resize "100x100" image.jpg thumb.jpg
```